# KendoUI MVC Helper Grid Paging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I am using the Asp.Net KendoUI Grid MVC helper but cannot get paging to work correctly. Specifically, I cannot get the total records to show.  This is the code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.FunctionList.AsEnumerable())
        .Name("Grid")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Server()
            .Total(50)
            .Model(model => model.Id(f => f.FunctionId))
            .Read(read => read.Action("Index", "Function"))
            .Update(update => update.Action("Edit", "Function"))
            .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Delete", "Function"))
            )

  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(f => f.FunctionName);
      columns.Bound(f => f.FunctionDescription);
      columns.Command(command => { command.Custom("Edit").Action("Edit", "Function").SendDataKeys(true); command.Destroy(); }).Width(200);

  })
.Scrollable()
.Groupable()
.Sortable()

.Pageable(pageable => pageable
                    .PageSizes(true)
                    .ButtonCount(5))

.Filterable(filterable => filterable
                    .Extra(false)
                    .Operators(ops => ops
                        .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                        .Contains("Contains")
                        .StartsWith("Starts with")
                        .EndsWith("Ends with")
                        .IsEqualTo("Equal to")
                        .IsNotEqualTo("Not Equal To")
                    )))    
    )
```

Note the .Total(50). Irrespective of the page size selected (5, 10 or 20) I get only 1 page i.e. the grid shows "1 to n of n items" where n is the page size. It should be showing "1 -5 of 50 items" for a page size of 5 and total records of 50.

The generated javascript (view source) shows that the Total(50) has no effect :

```
"pageSize":5,"page":1,"total":5,"serverPaging":true
```

Notice the "total":5 where it should be "total":50

Answer (score 1):

I am posting the whole grid which is working fine on my application . But i made a look at you code there is problem with you datasource attribute , you are missing ***.Ajax()*** and ***.ServerOperation(false)*** (I made pagination work after adding these two), compare it with mine and you'll find the real reason

```
    Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.asdry).Name("abc").Columns(c =>
     {
c.Bound(p => p.datetimecalculated).Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}");
         c.Bound("").ClientTemplate("#= purchaseCriteria(data) #").Title("Sold/Bought");
         c.Bound(p => p.numcontracts);
         c.Bound(p => p.entityid);
         c.Bound(p => p.leagueid);
         c.Bound("")
             .ClientTemplate("#= setSeasonYear(data) #")
             .Sortable(false)
             .Title("Year");

         c.Bound("")
             .ClientTemplate("#= setSeason(data) #")
             .Sortable(false)
             .Title("Season");
         c.Bound(p => p.contractmeasurable);
         c.Bound(p => p.price).ClientTemplate("#= moneyformat_at(price) #");
         c.Bound(p => p.profitorloss).ClientTemplate("#= moneyFormat(profitorloss) #");

     }).DataSource(
    d => d
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(false)

    )
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Resizable(resizing => resizing.Columns(true))
            )
```

**Update**
Reason for using these is as below
.Ajax() // Specify that ajax binding is used
.ServerOperation(false) // Paging, sorting, filtering and grouping will be done client-side

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/tutorials/ASP.NET/Hello%20Kendo%20UI/asp-net-hello-kendo-ui-part-1

This is a good tutorial for pagination!

You need to do a skip and take.

If your page size is 10 and your page number is 2 you want to basically do this sum

skip.((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)

soo if will take records 10-20
and shows 10 of them!

This may not make sense but the link is good! :)

Answer (score 0):

Set serverPaging of kendogrid to false:

```
serverPaging: false,
```